# Resize iFrame in facebook fan page

Tags: facebook

I want resize the iframe height of my tab page. I am trying FB.Canvas.SetSize method, also I try with jQuery and javascript resize the iframe but don´t work.

My application is not a Canvas.It is a tab page so i think "FB.Canvas method should not work with tab page".

How could resize my tab page on facebook profile?

How could drop the iFrame scrollbars on tab page?

Excuse me I also need to know if I could modify the share button with a custom image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Provide some code
2. Make sure you have the **Canvas Height** option is set to Settable under the App Advanced Settings
3. Use [asynchronous Loading](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#async-sdk) of your JS-SDK and put your `FB.Canvas.setSize();` inside the `fbAsyncInit` function
4. Please note that the `fbAsyncInit` function may fire (and hence your `FB.Canvas.setSize();`) *before* all images of your page are loaded! which means actual height of page is not reached *yet*!